# How to enable Location in Flutter with flutter_webview plugin?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview, geolocation

I am currently using flutter_webview plugin for a project. In one of the page, I need to get the user location information to calculate the distance. There is JavaScript running on the webpage to get the location.

Here is my sample code.

```
WebView(
  key: _key,
  initialUrl: "https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp",
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  onPageFinished: (_) {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  },
),
```

If I open the same page on chrome, it asks for the location permission. I wanted to implement something like that.

I tried using permissions on AndroidManifest file but could not make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to use [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_webview_plugin/latest/flutter_webview_plugin/WebviewScaffold-class.html), there is a geolocation property you can enable it.
check this code

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
return WebviewScaffold( 
  url: url, 
  withZoom: true, 
  hidden: true, 
  geolocationEnabled: true,
);
}
```

Comment: How to use this in main function?

Comment: this dependency now is deprecated and not support AndroidX. did you have alternate it?

Comment: Any solutions to this?