# Flutter WebView Location

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I am creating a WebView of this website
https://nearxt.com/
which asks for location when opened but when i use this link to create a webview in flutter
then it can not take location
i have also defined location in the application but webview cant recieve location

```
 SafeArea(
    child: WebView(
     javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      initialUrl: flutterUrl,
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller = webViewController;
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: This might help [check this answer on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64463007/13365250)

Comment: Have you tried this package ? 
https://pub.dev/packages/location

Answer (score 2):

This is unsupported in flutter. Even if you try to ask for location access using permission handler the app will deny it and still if you manually give the location permission to the app from your phone it still won't catch the real time location. Suggestion is to use plain old java for it you can find a lot of help around the internet about webview in java with location access it works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Use [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) to get users location

```
InAppWebView(
  initialUrlRequest:
      URLRequest(url: Uri.parse('your link here')),
  androidOnGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt:
      (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin) async {
    return GeolocationPermissionShowPromptResponse(
      origin: origin,
      allow: true,
      retain: true
    );
  },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible with [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter):

First, you need to add [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler), [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) and [webview_flutter_android](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_android) to your `pubspec.yaml` and run `flutter pub get`

```
dependencies:
  permission_handler: ^11.3.0
  webview_flutter: ^4.7.0
  webview_flutter_android: ^3.15.0
```

`permission_handler` requires additional setup for both iOS and Android, see the [readme](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/main/permission_handler/README.md) for more information.

Then you can use `setGeolocationPermissionsPromptCallbacks` to request the location permission from the user when the website tries to use the Geolocation API:

```
final controller = WebViewController()
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
  ..loadRequest('your_url');

final platformController = controller.platform;

if (platformController is AndroidWebViewController) {
  platformController.setGeolocationPermissionsPromptCallbacks(
    onShowPrompt: (request) async {
      // request location permission
      final locationPermissionStatus = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();
    
      // return the response
      return GeolocationPermissionsResponse(
        allow: locationPermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted,
        retain: false,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

And here's a full example:

```
class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebViewExample> createState() => _WebViewExampleState();
}

class _WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  late final WebViewController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..loadRequest('your_url');

    final platformController = controller.platform;
    if (platformController is AndroidWebViewController) {
      platformController.setGeolocationPermissionsPromptCallbacks(
        onShowPrompt: (request) async {
          // request location permission
          final locationPermissionStatus = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();

          // return the response
          return GeolocationPermissionsResponse(
            allow: locationPermissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted,
            retain: false,
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```