# How to enable geolocation on in app web view flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

I tried to create a web-view app, and the app need user position as input, I tried to add permission in android manifest, and use permission_handler but none of them works, I tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72759858/19793959

```
InAppWebView(
  key: webViewKey,
  initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
    url: Uri.parse("https://mprj.live/user/register.php")),
  androidOnGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt:
    (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin) async {
      return GeolocationPermissionShowPromptResponse(
         origin: origin, allow: true, retain: true);
    },
  initialOptions: options,
  androidOnPermissionRequest:
    (controller, origin, resources) async {
      return PermissionRequestResponse(
        resources: resources,
          action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
      },
),
```

And this is the error

```
E/cr_LocationProvider(18381): Caught security exception while registering for location updates from the system. The application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions.
E/cr_LocationProvider(18381): newErrorAvailable application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions.
I/flutter (18381): {message: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined, messageLevel: 3}
```